# Modificar datos automaticamente con PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Les comento que tengo una lista de notas en la cual me gustaria hacer que se actualice de forma automatica.

```
<?php
$list = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM notas WHERE chicas = '".$row_u['equipo']."'");
while ($fila = $lista->fetch()) { // lista de notas

if($row['complet'] == 1) {
?>
<span class="text-primary"><i class="svg-icon" data-feather="check-circle"></i></span>
<?php
} else {
?>
<a href="update.php?@=<?=$row['id'];?>" title="Imcomplete"><span class="text-light-c"><i class="svg-icon" data-feather="check-circle"></i></span></a>
<?php
}
?>
```

Este es el archivo update.php

```
<?php
include '../conn.php';

$code = $_GET['@'];

$sql = "UPDATE notas SET activa = '1' WHERE code = '".$code."'";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

header('location: ../');
?>
```

Quise usar `AJAX`, pero no se como hacer y tambien `JavaScript`, pero no se bien cual de los dos y tampoco se si usar lo que dije anteriormente puede afectar algo que este dentro de un `while`, ayudaaaa!

Codigo Javascript

```
function guardaryeditar(e)
{
e.preventDefault();
$("#btnGuardar").prop("disabled", true);
var formData = new FormData($("#formulario")[0]);

    $.ajax({
    url: "update.php?op=guardaryeditar",
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,

   success: function(datos)
   {
        mostrarform(false);
        tabla.ajax.reload();
   }
 });

limpiar();  
}
```

Busque para poder entender un poco mas lo que quiero hacer, pero no me funciona y no se que es lo que me quiere decir este codigo. Por favor, me gustaria que me expliquen asi puedo aprender. Gracias

Comment: Si necesitas el codigo vas por mal puerto. Trata de hacer algo aunque este mal para que podamos ayudarte mejor. La idea es que puedas aprender, pero tienes que aportar algo tu tambien! Y por favor, se mas amable con las personas de esta comunidad!

Comment: Gracias @previant y mil disculpas si los trate mal. Entende que estoy aprendiendo a programar sola y de a poco voy interiorizando mas en `php`. Ya modifique y agregue un codigo javascript pero no se cual es la diferencia.

Comment: La pregunta es interesante y daría para una respuesta interesante, pero no la entiendo del todo, el contexto es poco claro: *tengo una lista de notas en la cual me gustaria hacer que se actualice de forma automatica.*  ¿Qué significa *que se actualice de forma **automática***? Parece que tienes un link al lado de cada fila... Luego confundes conceptos: Ajax y Javascript no son alternativos, sino complementarios: Ajax es una herramienta que funciona a través de Javascript. Sería interesante también usar consultas preparadas aquí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto puedes hacerlo sin problemas con `Ajax` , pero agrégale el `id` a tu `title` para que el registro que selecciones lleve consigo ese valor al momento de darle `clic` y agregamos el vento onlick a enlace de esta manera:

```
<a href="#" onclick="update(this)" title="<?=$row['id'];?>">
    <span class="text-light-c">
        <i class="svg-icon" data-feather="check-circle"></i>
    </span>
</a>
```

Al momento de que hagas `click` en el enlace mandara a llamar a la `funcion` y se envía como parámetro.

```
function update(dato){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'update.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {id: dato.title},
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (data) {
            // exito
            console.log(data);
        }
    }); 
}
```

Y en tu `update.php` lo recibes por `$_POST`:

```
include '../conn.php';
$code = $_POST['id'];

$sql = "UPDATE notas SET activa = '1' WHERE code = '".$code."'";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

// header('location: ../');
```

Si vas a hacer los update por `AJAX` entonces no hagas una redireccion, puedes enviar una respuesta por medio de:

```
echo json_encode('Actualización exitosa!');
```

Y con el `console.log(data)` debes de ver en tu `consola` del `navegador` la respuesta, misma que puedes agregar a una alerta o algo ya mas estético para tu sitio web.

Comment: Esta es una alternativa a todas las demás, ya que puedes enviar el parámetro directamente a la función o puedes hacer uso por ejemplo del `title` en este caso que al final dan el mismo resultado.

Pero tomando en cuenta que es una petición en `ajax` que no debe ser redirigida si no que debe de llevar consigo una respuesta.

Comment: Gracias Eduardo, pero en consola me sale este error: `TypeError: $.ajax is not a function[Learn More] localhost:340:5
    update http://localhost/.../?@=1#:340
    onclick http://localhost/.../?@=1#:1`

Comment: y ademas ya tengo otro problema, porque si se modifico el estado el `if` de php ya no me va a hacer util y tendria que cambiar el icono desde `ajax` en modo activo o inactivo. Se que soy un poco lerda para aprender, pero trato de hacer el mayor esfuerzo!

Comment: Que versión de JQuery estas utilizando, porque es extrañ que te arroje que ajax no es una función.

Y no entiendo a que te refieres con que modificando el estado del if de php ya no te va a hacer util.

¿Eso esta dentro de tu pregunta?

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con esto... solo debes cambiar la `url: "ruta"` y cada cuanto quieres que se haga el refresh (actualmente está en 3000 = 3 seg),

AJAX

```
function sendRequest() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "./ruta/lista_de_notas.php",
        success:
            function (data) {
                $('#idEtiqueta').html(data);
            },
        complete: function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                sendRequest();  
            }, 3000);
        }
    });
};
$(function () {
    sendRequest();
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="idEtiqueta">
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias Kevin, use el scrip que me publicaste, pero no logro que haga cambio. Hice esto `<a href="update.php?@=<?=$row['id'];?>" id="idEtiqueta" title="Imcomplete"><span class="text-light-c"><i class="svg-icon" data-feather="check-circle"></i></span></a>`

Answer (score 1):

La naturaleza de la etiqueta  es abrirte una nueva url y recargar todo (incluyendo javascript) ademas de enviar datos por GET, estas entendiendo mal el como maneja ajax los datos:

De esta manera la llamada ajax no envia el id que queres enviar...

```
<a href="update.php?@=<?=$row['id'];?>" title="Imcomplete"><span class="text-light-c"><i class="svg-icon" data-feather="check-circle"></i></span></a>
```

Lo que tienes que hacer es pasar las variables por javascript, tu etiqueta html quedaria algo asi:

```
<a href="#" onclick="funcionAjax(event, <?php echo $row['id']; ?>);" title="Imcomplete"><span class="text-light-c"><i class="svg-icon" data-feather="check-circle"></i></span></a>
```

despues tu función que llama a ajax quedaria algo asi:

```
function funcionAjax(e, id) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: "update.php",
    type: "GET", //debe de ser el mismo metodo de recepción que el de tu update.php
    data: "@="+id, //puedes pasar así las variables o como un arreglo {"@":id}
    success: function(datos){
        //código en caso de éxito
    },
    error:{
        //código en caso de error
    }
 });
}
```